# series of commands using nohup

Tags: shell, unix, nohup

I have a series of commands that I want to use nohup with.

Each command can take a day or two, and sometimes I get disconnected from the terminal.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Method1:

```
nohup command1 && command2 && command3 ...
```

or
Method2:

```
nohup command1 && nohup command2 && nohup command3 ...
```

or
Method3:

```
echo -e "command1\ncommand2\n..." > commands_to_run
nohup sh commands_to_run
```

I can see method 3 might work, but it forces me to create a temp file. If I can  choose from only method 1 or 2, what is the right way?

Comment: I think (but don't know) that the answer is "either". But neither of these will let you reattach to see any output from the processes. If you want to be able to do that you want to look into something like GNU screen or tmux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nohup command1 && command2 && command3 ...
```

The `nohup` will apply only to `command1`. When it finishes (assuming it doesn't fail), `command2` will be executed without `nohup`, and will be vulnerable to a hangup signal.

```
nohup command1 && nohup command2 && nohup command3 ...
```

I don't think this would work. Each of the three commands will be protected by `nohup`, but the shell that handles the `&&` operators will not. If you logout before `command2` begins, I don't think it will be started; likewise for `command3`.

```
echo -e "command1\ncommand2\n..." > commands_to_run
nohup sh commands_to_run
```

I think this should work -- but there's another way that doesn't require creating a script:

```
nohup sh -c 'command1 && command2 && command3'
```

The shell is then protected from hangup signals, and I believe the three sub-commands are as well. If I'm mistaken on that last point, you could do:

```
nohup sh -c 'nohup command1 && nohup command2 && nohup command3'
```